# Placing cursor after lines appended via append / line

Tags: vim, append, text-cursor

I use the following function to insert a break in comments of the following format:

***Break:***

```
# Notes -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Function:***

```
" Insert RStudio like section break
function! InsertSectionBreak()
        let title = input("Section title: ")            " Collect title
        let title_length = strlen(title)                " Number of repetitions
        let times = 80 - (title_length + 1)
        let char = "-"                                  " Create line break
        let sep_line =  repeat(char, times)
        let final_string = '\n#' . ' ' . title . ' ' . sep_line " Create final title string
        call cursor( line('.')+1, 1)
        call append(line('.')+1, final_string)            " Get current line and insert string
endfunction

" Map function to keyboard shortcut ';s'
nmap <silent>  ;s  :call InsertSectionBreak()<CR>
```

## Problem

After performing the operation I would like to place the cursor one line below the created section.

### Desired behaviour:

```
# Notes -------------------------------------------------------------------

<cursor should land here>
```

### Current behaviour

The cursors stays on the current line.

```
<some code I'm typing when I exit insert mode and call ;s - cursor stays here>
# Notes -------------------------------------------------------------------

<cursor lands here>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a low-level function, `append()` is not affected by and also does not affect the cursor position. Therefore, you just need to adapt the `cursor()` arguments. I would also recommend to only change the cursor at the very end, to make the calculation based on `line('.')` easier:

```
function! InsertSectionBreak()
        let title = input("Section title: ")            " Collect title
        let title_length = strlen(title)                " Number of repetitions
        let times = 80 - (title_length + 1)
        let char = "-"                                  " Create line break
        let sep_line =  repeat(char, times)
        let final_string = '#' . ' ' . title . ' ' . sep_line " Create final title string
        call append(line('.')+1, ['', final_string])            " Get current line and insert string
        call cursor(line('.')+4, 1)
endfunction
```

#### Additional notes

- The `'\n#'` string includes a literal `\n`, not a newline character. For that, double quotes would have to be used. However, even that won't work with `append()` because it always inserts *as one text line*, rendering the newline as `^@`. To include a leading empty line, pass a List of lines instead, and make the first list element an empty string.
- You're using mostly low-level functions (`cursor()`, `append()`); you could have used higher-level functions (`:normal! jj` or `:execute lnum` for cursor positioning, `:put =final_string` for adding lines) instead. There would be more side effects (like adding to the jumplist, `:put` depending on and positioning the cursor already, and having the *change marks* delimit the added text); usually this is good (but it depends on the use case).
- Mappings that interactively query stuff from the user are not very Vim-like. I would have rather defined a custom command (e.g. `:Break {title}`) that takes the title as an argument, and maybe an additional (incomplete command-line) mapping for quick access `:nnoremap ;s :Break<Space>`. This way, you could easily repeat the last insertion with the same title via `@:`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks very much for comprehensive and instructive answer and pointing additional shortcomings like wrong use of `\n` in my code.